# Running multiple scheduler jobs from a single notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run multiple scheduler jobs from a single notebook, but for some reason its not working. In my notebook, both of these are in the same cell, but only sched1 executes and writes its csv file, while sched2 does not execute:

```
    sched1 = BlockingScheduler(timezone='US/Central')
    sched1.add_job(df.to_csv('file1.csv'), CronTrigger(hour = '12'
                                    minute = '15'), 
                  misfire_grace_time = 300, coalesce = True)
    sched1.start()

    sched2 = BlockingScheduler(timezone='US/Central')
    sched2.add_job(df.to_csv('file2.csv'), CronTrigger(hour = '12'
                                    minute = '16'), 
                  misfire_grace_time = 300, coalesce = True)
    sched2.start()
```

Do I need to have an individual scheduler for each terminal + notebook, or can I run multiple schedulers from a single notebook?

Comment: These 2 are function definition. Are you sure you are not calling the function somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete the function definition. Fixed now

Comment: Looking at the documentation https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#:~:text=BlockingScheduler%20is%20the%20simplest%20possible,e.g.%20to%20build%20a%20daemon).&text=examples%2Fschedulers%2Fblocking.py%20(view%20online). The `start` will block the python process and never go forward.

Comment: If you want to schedule multiple jobs, you will need to use another scheduler : see the `choosing scheduler ` section here https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html